# Simple calculator with select form and text fields

Tags: javascript

I tried to do a simple calculator with select form and text fields and it doesn't work.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFile.css" />
    <script src="jsFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello! Please put two numbers below and choose action:</p>
    <p>
    <input type="text" id="firstNum" />
    <select id="fallDown">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option value="add" id="add">+</option>
    <option value="less" id="less">-</option>
    <option value="times" id="times">*</option>
    <option value="howin" id="howin">/</option>
    <input type="text" id="secNum" /><br>
    <button onclick="calcuMath()">Result here!</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
<body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function calcuMath(){
    var z;
    var x=document.getElementById("firstNum");
    var y=document.getElementById("secNum");
    var sel=document.getElementById("fallDown");
    var selection=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    var more=document.getElementById("add");
    var pahot=document.getElementById("less";
    var kaful=document.getElementById("times");
    var hiluk=document.getElementById("howin");
    if(selection.value=="add"){
        z=x+y;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="The result is "+z+".";
}
```

It doesn't write the result of the two numbers and I don't know if it even rekon them (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: `z = x + y` adds two DOM elements and assigns the result to `z`. You cannot make elements reproduce that way, so I guess you forgot to access their `value` attributes instead.

Comment: Its doesnt write the result of the two numbers and I dont know if it even rekon them (sorry for my bad english) and Fredric can you tell me the exact problem (I mean where in the code it isnt right and how to solve it??)

Answer (score 1):

you should get the `value` of element

```
var x = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
```

you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) simply:

see **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UaZ65/2/)**

```
$("#calc").on("click", function(){

    switch($("#fallDown").val())
    {
        case "add":{
    $("#result").html(
        parseFloat($("#firstNum").val())+parseFloat($("#secNum").val())
    );}
            break;
            //etc
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things you need to change:

Get the value from your input boxes and parse numbers from them:

```
var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("firstNum").value);
var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("secNum").value);
```

Selection already has the value so remove it in the comparison:

```
if (selection=="add") {
```

In case you missed it as well, there's a missing closing parenthesis on this line:

```
var pahot=document.getElementById("less";
```

Comment: what's mean the 10 after the value??

Comment: Why do you assume there will only be integers?

Comment: Thank's its works for me.. and how do i change that it will also works with number with decimel??

Comment: Good point @j08691; changed to parseFloat.

Comment: @user3070878 parseInt takes a second parameter that defines the radix (the base).

Answer (score 0):

Your form seems fine, but your JS should be:

```
function calcuMath() {
    var z;
    var x = document.getElementById("firstNum").value; // NEED .value
    var y = document.getElementById("secNum").value; // NEED .value
    var sel = document.getElementById("fallDown");
    var selection = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    var more = document.getElementById("add");
    var pahot = document.getElementById("less");
    var kaful = document.getElementById("times");
    var hiluk = document.getElementById("howin");
    if (selection == "add") { // Remove .value
        z = parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y); // Convert from strings to floats
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The result is " + z + ".";
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FNgxT/)**

Comment: It's still doesnt write the result...

Comment: In the fiddle? Works for me when you try addition.

Answer (score 0):

*JavaScript has math built in!* Why build an interpreter for an interpreted language?

HTML

```
Math: <input id="math" type="text"/><br><br>
Result: <p id="result"></p>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('math').oninput = function () {
    if (!(/^[A-z]+$/g.test(this.value))) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = eval(this.value);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Illegal character.';
    }
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/7Wa94/#base**

Comment: I'd avoid running `eval` on user input if possible.

Comment: I would usually agree, but it doesn't pose a security risk, because users always have access to a javascript console. I feel that for a calculator, eval is a perfect solution. Optimally in this situation, I would recommend math.js @BernhardHofmann